# anychart stock with julian date on x axis

Tags: stock, anychart

Is it possible to use a Julian date in stock graph or to show x axis with julian date format?
I try to format x axis using a function that return Julian date without any success

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to [change the labels of a stock chart to a Julian Year Date](https://playground.anychart.com/MmJrmULt/2), using custom [formatting functions and tickvalue](https://api.anychart.com/anychart.core.ui.LabelsFactory#category-specific-settings).
In case you are looking for an [absolute Julian date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day), you can explore a similar method of [changing a Gregorian calendar to a Julian](https://playground.anychart.com/wHRQJAJD).
Example of conversion functions:

```
// Converting Calendar to a Julian
Date.prototype.julianDayOfTheYear=function(){
    var j=parseInt((this.getTime()-new Date('Dec 30,'+(this.getFullYear()-1)+' 23:00:00').getTime())/86400000).toString(),
    i=3-j.length;
    while(i-->0)j=0+j;
    
    return j
};

// Converting Calendar to a Julian Year Date
Date.prototype.julianDayOfTheYear=function(){
    var j=parseInt((this.getTime()-new Date('Dec 30,'+(this.getFullYear()-1)+' 23:00:00').getTime())/86400000).toString(),
    i=3-j.length;
    while(i-->0)j=0+j;
    
    return j
};
```

Example of formatting functions:

```
// Current Julian date getter function
    var julianGetter = (e) => {
    var labelDate = new Date(e);
    var untrimmedData = labelDate.julianDayOfTheYear();
    
    // Trimming 0's at the start of the date
    for (var i = 0; i < untrimmedData.length; i++) {
        if (untrimmedData.charAt(i) == '0') {
         untrimmedData = untrimmedData.slice(1);
         i--; // update index to account for the removed character
        } else { break }
    }
    return untrimmedData;
}

// Changing labels of xAxis to Julian
    chart.plot(0).xAxis().labels().format((e)=>julianGetter(e.tickValue))
  
  // Changing minor labels of xAxis to Julian
    chart.plot(0).xAxis().minorLabels().format((e)=>julianGetter(e.tickValue))
```

We hope these methods will fit your needs well.